# Can I apply symmetry to this boundary value problem (BVP)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, boundary-conditions, thermal-conductivity

Let's say I have a hollow cylindrical shell with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ and length $L$. The temperature at at z=L is $T_{2}$ and the temperature at z=0 is $T_{1}$. There is also an ambient temperature of $T_{1}$ outside the shell. The inner radius is insulated. Right now the boundary conditions I am working with are
$$T(r,L)=T_{2}$$
$$T(r,0)=T_{1}$$
$$-k\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right|_{r=b}=h[T(b,L)-T_{1}]$$
$$\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right|_{r=a}=0$$

Instead of saying the inner radius is insulated, can I use the problem's symmetry about the radial coordinate to make the last boundary condition as

$$\left. \frac{\partial T}{\partial r} \right|_{r=0}=0$$

so that the solution is easier to determine when I apply my boundary conditions? I am not sure if the fact that it is a hollow cylinder means I cannot do that like I normally would apply symmetry.

EDIT: The problem states the inner side is well insulated

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to relax the boundary condition where $\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}|_{r=a} = 0$ , because the temperature function is defined for $a\leq r\leq b$ and $0\leq z\leq L$.

If you don't consider the boundary condition, you are eliminating the insulation on the inner surface of the cylinder, whereas the insulation on the inner side is not condition enough to guarantee that the heat transfer on the inner surface is null and therefore you will have to consider the condition again.

Maybe you can check this link: http://www.ewp.rpi.edu/hartford/~ernesto/S2006/CHT/Notes/ch03.pdf, on the steady state multidimensional problem for a analytical solution. If not, you can always try a numerical solving method.